# session_start(): Failed to read session data: redis (path: tcp://127.0.0.1:6380) in Yii2?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am deploying my project on Ubuntu server using docker yml file here i am installing the redis server in docker yml file
 `- apt-get install -y redis-server`

> Why it is returned this error. How i can configured the redis server
>   using yml file?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam

Comment: @csminb have a look

Comment: Have a look at how to as a question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Also, trying to tag users to help you is not a great way to get help. In addition, this is tagged with `yii2` - while the question seem to be about docker and redis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the json file
`"yiisoft/yii2-redis": "~2.0.0"`
update the composer
Here add this to your common/config/main.php use this only for server not for your local computer using wamp and xamp

```
'redis'         => [
    'class'    => 'yii\redis\Connection',
    'hostname' => '127.0.0.1',
    'port'     => 6379,
    'database' => 0,
],
'session'       => [
    'class' => 'yii\redis\Session',
],
```

And also install redis on server the default port here is 6379 but you change it in your server redis configuration and add it to here in port.

> Note: This worked for me in Ubuntu server.